# How to terminate Rest Assured connection in case no response received after period of time

Tags: rest-assured, connection-timeout

I am using Rest Assured 4 to test our product.
In some cases, rest connection of a single request lasts more then an hour.
I would like to terminate a connection in case no response of any king is back after some period of time.

any way to do that?
thanks